# Debugging Bitcoin Unit Tests

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, debugging, unit-test

I am running the unit tests from bitcoin source using `make check`, and would like to debug the tests using `LogPrint` in the bitcoin source files. I read in the [Test Docs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/test) that logs are only output to `test_framework.log`, but I'm unable to locate this file. Where should I be able to find it? Or perhaps there is a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the two kinds of tests. Unit tests are compiled into a separate binary and run by `make check`. Functional tests are testing the RPC commands and have to be run explicitly using the `test_runner.py` script. `test_framework.log` is only created by the functional tests. The documentation for the unit tests can be found [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/test/README.md).

To print messages in the unit tests, you cannot use `LogPrintf`. Instead use `BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE` and `BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE` to print messages from the tests. You will have to run the test binary directly (`src/test/test_bitcoin`) with `--log_level=all` to see the messages.

To print from the source files themselves, you could use `fprintf()` and print your messages to stderr.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, I think this will allow printing messages from the test files, but what about the source files?  Eg. `net_processing.cpp`

Comment: You can use `fprintf`. Updated the answer

Comment: nit: The test_runner.py script allows you to run all functional tests in parallel but you don't *have* to use it.